# Kubernetes Ingress nginx installation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to install ingress-nginx in minikube on windows. I remember when I did this earlier by following below [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) link, it had a mandatory step to install deployables -

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
```

But I don't see this anymore valid. If you see installation guide it does not have any step before provider specific commands.

So can someone help to clarify if am missing anything? how would `ingress-nginx-controller` get created without executing above command which itself is missing in the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube already has nginx ingress packaged as an add-on part of Minikube installation. You just need to enable it via

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Comment: thanks. figured out its already installed. But if you see doc link it asks to check `kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx` which is not true as its part of `kube-system`